# universal-cli build for production and upload on shared server

Tags: angular, typescript, rendering

I'm building an app using universal-cli for Angular 2 in order to have server rendered view.

Everything works well on localhost (I can see the source code), but when I try to build the project, I end up with two directories in dist folder (client and server) and no other files

Now the question is how I need to upload the project on a shared server and still have the server rendered?! source code.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you building your application? What do your build scripts look like? Is your application based on any other project that we could reference? Your question is too broad without any more details.

Comment: Simply followed the installation guide provided by universal-cli and to build I run this command  `ung build --prod --env=prod`
I have nothing added to this setup...just the blank app.